# Django Admin Drag and Drop

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, drag-and-drop, django-admin

Looking for some guidance because I'm entering new territory here in terms of my Django experience.  I'm writing a reprographics request app so have created a couple of models:

```
class Job(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?


class Resource(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?
  job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
  file = models.FileField(upload_to="repro/")
```

The admin view includes the resource as inline

```
class ResourceInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Resource
        extra = 0

class JobAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Job
    list_display = ['requestedby','account','requestdate','requireddate','noofsides','noofcopies']
    list_filter = ['requireddate']
    search_fields = ['requestedby','account']
    form = JobForm
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['requestedby','account','requestdate','requireddate','noofsides','noofcopies'] }),
        ('Requirements', {'fields': ['color','sided','paper','finishing']}),
        ('Additional Information', {'fields': ['additionalinfo']}),

    ]
    inlines = [ResourceInline]
admin.site.register(Job,JobAdmin)
```

I'm planning to use [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) and have got myself a change_form.html that I can customise but at this point I'm a bit lost.  How can I replace the inline with my dropzone area and get it working?

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Chris

Comment: Check out https://django-admin-sortable.readthedocs.io or https://django-admin-sortable2.readthedocs.io

Answer (score 5):

Use [adminsortable2](https://django-admin-sortable2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to **drag and drop in Django Admin**. This is [the github link](https://github.com/jrief/django-admin-sortable2).

So in you case, the code with [adminsortable2](https://django-admin-sortable2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is this below.

**"models.py"**:

```py
from django.db import models

class Job(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    my_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['my_order']
  
class Resource(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="repro/")
    my_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['my_order']
```

**"admin.js"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from adminsortable2.admin import SortableAdminMixin, SortableInlineAdminMixin
from .models import Job, Resource

class ResourceInline(SortableInlineAdminMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    model = Resource
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Job)
class JobAdmin(SortableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['requestedby','account','requestdate','requireddate','noofsides','noofcopies']
    list_filter = ['requireddate']
    search_fields = ['requestedby','account']
    form = JobForm
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['requestedby','account','requestdate','requireddate','noofsides','noofcopies'] }),
        ('Requirements', {'fields': ['color','sided','paper','finishing']}),
        ('Additional Information', {'fields': ['additionalinfo']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ResourceInline]
```

Then, run this command below after writing the code above to save your sorting:

```
python manage.py reorder <app.model>
```

So, in your case, I don't know **your app name** so if your app name is **"work"** and I know **your model names "Job" and "Resource"** so run this command below to save your sorting:

```
python manage.py reorder work.Job work.Resource
```